# Helix core get a folder version (with content)

Tags: perforce

in Helix Core one can easy find a file version.

**Is there a way to get a folder version**, taking into account all the folder content (if any file inside changed, folder verion should change too)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "folder version" is a changelist associated with a folder.  Do:

```
p4 changes //depot/folder/...
```

Those numbers are the "versions" of the folder.  You can do:

```
p4 sync //depot/folder/...@N
```

to sync to any one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Files are versioned, but folders are not.